# Uppercase within HTML tag vs CSS text-transform

Tags: html, css

Is there a difference between directly writing uppercase text within HTML tag like this:

```
<h3> MY TEXT HERE </h3>
```

or not having directly uppercase and transform it with CSS like this:

```
<h3> My text here </h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 { text-transform: uppercase;} ;
```

Which would load faster in the browser? And why?

Comment: `Which would load faster in the browser?` Does it matter?

Comment: The only difference is that using `text-transform` requires CSS (this is not a problem) and, should you copy & paste that text into another document, it won't remain uppercase; the speed difference is infinitesimal, I'd imagine.

Comment: The main difference is in that you are actually transporting different _content_ in your HTML code. And “faster” resp. “performance” is absolutely not an issue here. (How come people always worry about such absolutely minor things that have no real-world relevance whatsoever …?)

Comment: Use CSS for styling purposes. If you change your mind later on, then removing that CSS property will be enough. Updating all html would be a nightmare.

Comment: @DavidThomas: _“The only difference is that using text-transform requires JavaScript”_ – you are either kidding, or still using NetScape 4 … (which had JCSS, a JS-based CSS implementation, AFAIK.)

Comment: No, I mis-typed; and yes, I realised how stupid that statement was, and I corrected it.

Comment: @CBroe - [JSSS](http://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822) not JCSS.

Comment: @Alohci: Thanks, I knew it was something like that … pretty amazing concept, back in the day …

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a question of which would load faster even though the upper case would "load faster" than loading the extra bytes from the css.

In my opinion, there is a question of accessibility involved in that matter.

You should write the text as it is supposed to be written for a vocal reader to read it (for blind people).

Morevover, I would personnaly write it with the text-transform as it's easy to change if you have a lot of h3 in your website and you don't want to write them all over again if you change the way your h3s look.

Comment: Agreed – the decision should be based on the content itself. An acronym/company name stylized in uppercase as per CD/CI etc. should be uppercase in HTML, naturally. If it is a simple “styling” matter, such as a headline in uppercase for design reasons, then CSS is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference in document *content*, “MY TEXT HERE” versus “My text here” (just styled to be *rendered* in all uppercase). This matters in non-CSS rendering situations, in scripting, and other automated processing. Most search engines seem to dealt with texts in a case-insignificant manner, but this is not guaranteed and may change, at least in some situations. When text is copied and pasted from an HTML document, all styling is often lost so that you only get the content.

Any difference in speed on loading is most probably immaterial, but obviously the version that has the desired spelling in the content is faster than one that needs a style sheet rule to be loaded and applied.

Comment: Yes, search engines might be an issue – not only in how they index text (in that it should indeed not matter, possible edge cases aside) – but in what they display as a snippet/excerpt for the page content in their search results. If it is important that `FOO` shows up in uppercase there, then it should be written as `FOO` in the HTML. (But in that case it is probably an acronym, company name or such stylized in uppercase anyway, so logically it belongs as such in the HTML to begin with.)

Answer (score 3):

Logically speaking, writing it uppercase directly in the HTML source would save the browser the trouble of rendering the style rule and applying a transform to the text.

But the difference of the page load speed would be irrelevant, and not noticed...

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the accessibility issues with all-caps. `text-transform: uppercase` is better for accessibility than typing all-caps into your HTML markup. That said, [according to WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/fonts/#caps), all-caps can be an accessibility problem in general, whether used in your HTML or using CSS.

Here are some of the problems with all-caps:

1. "Lengthy segments of capitalized content are more difficult to read."
2. "Screen readers generally do not read text differently if it is in all capital letters, so listeners will not know that the author is giving emphasis to the text."
3. "In some cases, a screen reader may interpret ALL CAPITAL text as being an acronym and may read it as letters rather than words."